# Calculate the required water for humidity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. I have a humidifier, and a closed room. Basically, I want to know the required water to reach a certain level of humidity.

My room volume is 42 meter cube. I want to know how many liters are required to get to xx% humidity. What's the equation used and if water/humidity is a linear equation.

Comment: Hadn't you asked this same question before? . Please note that Homework questions are supposed to supposed to show more effort. For more details, please see the [Homework Policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: No I just signed up. And this is not a homework (not sure why you think it is). I have a humidifier, and I think its humidistat is not working correctly, so I want to make the math on my own.

Comment: It doesn't need to be real homework. See the linked homework policy.   I guess someone else had asked a similiar question, then.

Comment: First you'll need the height of the room, to get the volume...

Answer (score 1):

Find the volume of the room in cubic meters.  Measure the temperature of the air.

Find a table of "Moisture Content of Saturated Air", or "Maximum Moisture Content of Air" vs Temperature.

Multiply the appropriate value from the table at the room temperature by the volume  by the RH, to obtain the grams of moisture in the room...